# Pop-up to enter required column fields for uploaded file in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

After moving to the "new experience", Microsoft has decided to remove the pop-up window that would require you to enter all the required info associated with the file being uploaded. Instead, we have a colored field "required info", which I am sure most of the uploaders will skip.

Is there a possibility to make a pop-up similar to the one provided in classic SharePoint, where you would have to enter information to complete the upload? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:enable "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" in library settings so user need to fill in required information before they check it in.

[image]

Comment: Hey Lee, unfortunately this does not show a pop-up or a similar message to add required information. Some of the users are going to be completely new to SharePoint and this might be overlooked by them.